# User microphone permissions in Swift Playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground, user-permissions

I am trying to access the user's microphone for mic input in a game I am making, using AVFoundation (specifically installTap:onBus:) for ios. In a regular xcode project, you would request access form the user and write the NSMicrophoneUsageDescription to the info.plist.

However, due to the nature of playgrounds, they don't have an info.plist to write to. The result is that, after requesting permissions (popup shows to the user), the playground crashes since it can't write to the info.plist file! It doesn't give me a real error log, so I deduced that this was the error by running the same code in an xcode project.

Is there any way to force playgrounds to write to a specific info.plist file / get around this permission in playgrounds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [added custom key to info.plist, when I access from playground in Swift, it is nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562262/added-custom-key-to-info-plist-when-i-access-from-playground-in-swift-it-is-ni)