# Xcode Playground Microphone Permissions within Packages

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

I'm working on an iOS Swift Package/framework and we have a simple microphone input class that will assign the microphone input level to a variable to control visuals.

The class works fine when I use the class in a traditional app. The simulator properly asks for permissions, as does the actual iPhone. It does this through the info.plists file which is properly configured with the microphone privacy setting and explanation string.

As a part of the framework, we are also including Xcode Playgrounds within the package as   a set of tutorials. I am trying to create a microphone example. Because the playgrounds are inside of a Swift Package/framework, I'm unsure if it's possible to attach an info.plists file or even if that is the proper workflow.

My question is this:

Is there any way to get Xcode/the playground to ask for permission to use the mic from within a SwiftPackage/framework? Is there a place I could put an info.plist to make it work?

Comment: Duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562262/added-custom-key-to-info-plist-when-i-access-from-playground-in-swift-it-is-ni)

Comment: The link you are providing explains how to access a .plist file from within a Playground in order to use a custom key. However it does not actually talk about using that .plist file to get Xcode to request permission for microphone use. And it doesn't discuss any ways to access privacy permissions from a Playground, which is the larger intent of my question. That remains unanswered, hence my original question.